# Является ли оператор функцией?

Tags: c++

Является ли оператор функцией? Например при перегрузке оператора присваивания для определенного класса, мы можем вызвать его как обычную функцию. Но например является ли if функцией и т. д.

Comment: в с++ if не является функцией. но есть тернарный оператор, который может себя вести как функция.

Comment: Тернарный оператор - плохой пример. Функция вычисляет свои аргументы до вызова, тернарный оператор один из аргументов не вычисляет никогда.

Comment: if тоже не вычисляет одну половину, и ничего же. более того, в некоторых языках if вполне себе ведет себя как функция.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тут терминологическая путаница связанная с переводом английских терминов на русский язык:

- *statement* (`if`, `while`, `;` и т.д.)  — наименьшая автономная часть языка программирования; программная команда. Как туманно говорит стандарт C11<sup>¹</sup> ([*6.8/2*](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.8p1)): «То что задаёт действие, которое должно быть выполнено».

В русской традиции этот термин часто переводится, как ***оператор***.

- *operator* (`+`, `-`, `*`) — это обозначение (*symbol*), определяющее выполняемую операцию и обладающее собственной лексической и семантической значимостью (перефразировав C11 [*6.4.6/2*](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.4.6)).

  Для этого используют термин ***операция***.

Так вот, в языке C++ нет перегрузки *операторов* (*statement*), есть перегрузка некоторых *операций* (*operator*). Также в литературе для перевода этой пары терминов часто используют пару терминов *инструкция*/*оператор* соответственно<sup>²</sup>. Собственно из-за этой каши эти понятия часто смешиваются, хотя, о чём именно говорят, часто и так понятно из контекста, надо просто иметь в виду, что это разные вещи.

При этом в С++ ни *операторы*, ни *операции* не являются ни *функциями*, ни методами. Сделать что-то вроде `foo.operator+(bar)` можно только для своего типа, но для встроенных типов, например, `int` такое не пройдёт.

---

<sup>¹ Стандарт С++ вообще не утруждает себя текстовыми определениями, а просто ограничивается заданием грамматики: [stmt.stmt](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.stmt)</sup>

<sup>² Спасибо *@Mikhailo* за уточнение</sup>

Comment: Мне кажется, что перегруженные (не встроенные) операторы все-таки могут считаться функциями. Грамматика у них с функциями одна, на них могут указывать указатели-на-функции[-члены], и т. д.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, если переходить на уровень теологических споров, то в [писании](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.oper) это называется *operator function* (х.з. как на русском... *операционная функция* ?) и она вызывается при вычислении *операции*, которую она реализует... по тексту, я бы сказал, что всё же *operator function* является *функцией*, но сама собой всё же __не__ является *операцией*.

Comment: Чаще всего (по крайней мере в той, что читаю я :)) в русской литературе statement переводится как инструкция, как я понимаю, именно для того, чтоб не переводить как оператор.

Comment: @Mikhailo, и правда... вариант «инструкция» как-то раньше просто не замечал... сейчас взял подборку книжек с полки... по Си оказалось: оператор/операция: (Си) в пер. Прата и у Подбельского, (C++) в пер. Страуструпа; инструкция/оператор: (C) K&R, (C++) — в пер. Шилдта и Липпмана... *предложение* — вариант из мира SQL в основном, ну и какой-то очень древней литературы...

Answer (score 1):

Оператор не является функцией.

Подробнее про операторы

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operators-c-c/

http://natalia.appmat.ru/c&c++/lezione2.php

https://ravesli.com/urok-17-operatory-v-s/#toc-1

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

[image: Операторы в C++]

Comment: Но тогда почему перегруженный оператор можно вызвать в качестве функции?

Comment: @n1kzzz, [язык такой](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/), можете угробить всю свою жизнь в поисках глубокого смысла в нем.

Comment: Плохая картинка. `!` и `~` обозначены как бинарные, `+` и `-` тоже только как бинарные.